# why version dependency needs to be specified?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have pom.xml like,

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>

        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am unable to understand why am I required to specify version on cdi-api under dependencies when it is already defined in microprofile (inside dependencymanagement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pom isn't a standard bom that would define version of the dependencies but must be used like a standard dependency: https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-bom

> This style of BOM does not go in a
>   dependencyManagement section, using import
>   scope, and you cannot add dependencies declared in the BOM without
>   version elements as is typically done with that style of BOM.

You actually need to depend on that pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>    
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to add the type pom and either specify the version or reference this version in your dependency management with type pom if you want everything to work. glytching forgot the type pom, that's why this doesn't work.

Comment: I knew something is different with this pom but didn't knew what and how to get it working. kudos! Do you know why is it defined differently, or when to define pom files in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The [`org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile` artifact](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/microprofile/microprofile/1.3/microprofile-1.3.pom) declares a dependency on `javax.enterprise:cdi-api` so if you declare `org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile` as a dependency in your POM then `javax.enterprise:cdi-api` will be provided transitively.

In the example in your question you declared `org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile` in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, this section consolidates management of the version, scope, and exclusions for each dependency but in order to use that dependency in your project you **must** include it in the `<dependency>` section.

So, if you add this to your `<dependency>` section ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
    <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>    
</dependency>
```

... then `org.eclipse.microprofile:microprofile` will be included in your project and hence `javax.enterprise:cdi-api` will be included transitively and you won't have to declare it explicitly.

Comment: this solution is giving error as it gives fails for version of microprofile not provided.

Comment: Could you be specific about what "gives fails for version of microprofile not provided" means? Ideally you would provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is the example, pom.xml posted above. if I copy paste your suggestion to given pom.xml under dependencies (like cdi-api) , it complains for version of microprofile not provided.

Comment: @techtrainer: It is not working, because you use the scope `import`.